# How to get environment variables in a DOS assembly program

Tags: assembly, environment-variables, dos, x86-16

I have to do program in assembly which gets and prints environments variables DOS system. I was looking and unfortunately I can't find a solution.

Comment: Do you know how to access the environment block?

Comment: I only found a information about PSP block https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_Segment_Prefix
Is that what you mean?

Comment: It's a good start.  Now I know what kind of answer is useful to you.  Let me write one.

Comment: Are you writing a COM or an EXE binary?

Comment: COM format. I use org 100h directive

Answer (score 3):

DOS stores the environment variables for your process in the [*environment block*](http://www.techhelpmanual.com/346-dos_environment.html).  The environment block is a data structure that contains NUL-terminated pairs of environment variables and their values. The final entry of the environment block is just an empty string.

```
environment_block:
        db      'COMSPEC=c:\command.com',0
        db      'PROMPT=$p$g',0
        db      'WP=c:\wordproc',0
        db      'PATH=d:\;c:\dos;c:\utils',0
        db      0
```

To find the environment block, first retrieve a pointer to the PSP.  In a COM binary, the PSP can be found at offset `0000` in any segment.  In an EXE binary, it's in offset `0000` of segment `DS` and `ES`.  If you need to load other segment selectors, make sure to remember a copy of the original value of `DS` so you can find your PSP.

The segment of the environment block can then be found at address `002c` in the PSP:

```
        ; assuming DS is the segment of the PSP
        mov     es, [2ch]    ; ES:0000h now points to the environment block
```

You can then process the variables in the environment block like any other sequence of strings.